# How do I load a Media entity from a File entity?

Tags: 8, media, files

I have a File entity loaded programmatically. I want to load a Media entity from it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to load the Media entity the File entity belongs to? Or you want to create a new Media entity and add the File entity you've created to that File entity?

Comment: Yes exactly i want to load the Media entity the File belongs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example - if your `File` entity is loaded in a variable named `$file`, and the field name on the `Media` entity is `field_media_image`:

```
$media_entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->loadByProperties([
  'field_media_image' => $file->id(),
]);

$media_entity = is_array($media_entities) ? array_pop($media_entities) : NULL;
```

Note1 : If the `File` object belongs to more than a single `Media` entity, you will need to loop through `$media_entities` to find the one you want.

Note 2: `$media_entity` will either contain the `Media` entity the `File` entity belongs to, or be `NULL` if the `File` entity doesn't belong to a `Media` entity.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found a good answer, i used :

`$result = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);`

and then in the $result i am checking if any keys called `media` exist. If so, i can then load my Media :)

Comment: There is an API for doing what you want, where you don't have to do the same checks you noted. Please see my answer to this question.